# Is It Possible to have a primary key and auto increment key associated to two fields respectively?

Tags: mysql, database

Is It Possible to have a primary key and auto increment key associated to two fields respectively?

Like wise, In a table there are 3 fields, say, ID, name and age..
Then is it possible that "`ID is autoincrment key and name is primary key`"?

Comment: Please Concentrate on the LIKEwISE statement I have Given.. U all are getting me wronmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html):

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT  column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value.

So as long as you satisfy those conditions, there's no mention that it has to also be the primary key. So you should be able to have the primary key and a separate `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (though I'm not sure why you'd want to).

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one primary index in the table.
if your `name` field is really has primary index purpose, you don't need an auto increment field. But I really doubt that. What's the real `name` field purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Also according to the MySQL Documentation:

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify an AUTO_INCREMENT secondary column in a multiple-column key. See Section 3.6.9, “[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)”.

So if you're using MyISAM, you can do something close to what you've asked (if I'm interpreting your question correctly): you can use a composite PRIMARY KEY, and one of them can be an INT type and use the AUTO_INCREMENT property.

Best thing, read the documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the autoincrement key as the PK and put a unique index on the name field.